# Find an affine transformation for points

Tags: systems-of-equations, transformation, affine-geometry

I have to find one affine transformation that maps the point P=(1,1,1) to P'=(-1,-1,-1), the point P=(-1,-1,-1)' to P=(1,1,1) and the point Q=(0,0,0) to Q'=(2,2,2).
I started with a sketch and think that it is not possible to map both points with one affine transformation, but I must somehow prove that.
So I take the formula: x' = a + Ax and started to fill in what we know about. We know that a = (2,2,2) to be able to map Q and we are looking for a matrix that can also transform P to P'. So I filled in P as x, and P' as x'.

$\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-1\\-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\2\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}a11+a12+a13\\a21+a22+a23\\a32+a32+a33\end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Then I get 3 equations with 9 variables so I'm not sure how to solve it:

I: a11 + a12 + a13 = -3

II: a21 + a22 + a23 = -3

III: a31 + a32 + a33 = -3

Am I on the right way? How can I solve this equations?

Comment: I don’t think that you meant to have pluses in that matrix. You’ve effectively got the product of two column vectors, which is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve got another three equations that come from the constraint $P'\mapsto P$ that you can add to the system. You will very quickly find that it’s inconsistent.

However, you can reach the same conclusion without expanding into individual matrix elements. Decompose the transformation into a linear transformation matrix $M$ and a translation, as you’ve done. The given constraints are that $M(1,1,1)^T+(2,2,2)^T=(-1,-1,-1)^T$ and $M(-1,-1,-1)^T+(2,2,2)^T=(1,1,1)^T$. Rearranging the the first one gives $M(1,1,1)^T=(-3,-3,-3)^T$, while by linearity, $M(-1,-1,-1)^T=-M(1,1,1)^T$, so the second constraint becomes $M(1,1,1)^T=(1,1,1)^T$, which is clearly impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You have done it right. Why do you think it is not possible? Just take the matrix $A_{ij}=-1 \; \forall i,j=1,2,3$. Then you have $a+AP=P'$ and $a+AQ=Q'$. You don't have to find all the possible solutions, just find the easiest one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply, I've noticed that I haven't described the problem correctly.
I can find an affine transformation that maps P to P' and Q to Q', but the problem is, that it must also be possible to map P' to P. (I've updated the question according to this.)

So I am looking for one affine transformation that can map P to P', P' to P and Q to Q'.
Here the problem is, that I can't find a solution that maps P to P' and P' to P while considering the mapping Q to Q'. When I only consider P to P' and Q to Q' then the mapping didn't work for P' to P.